# Java String split by comma

Tags: java

I have this code down below that gives me this output

```
1,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,3,4,5,5,4,64,
[Ljava.lang.String;@3e25a5
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
[I@19821f
```

The input.txt file contains  1,2,3,4,3,4,5,4,3,5,3,4,5,5,4,64,

The code is this. It is clear there is a simple error in splitting but I find it hard to find what.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
        DataInputStream  dat = new DataInputStream (fstream);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dat));
        String[] str ;

        int arr[] = new int [100];


        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {

                System.out.println(line);
                str = line.split(",");
                System.out.println(str);

                for(int i = 0 ;i<str.length ; i++)
                {
                    arr[i]= Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
                    System.out.println(arr);
                }
            }

        fstream.close();

    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }


}
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: You're going to get a `NumberFormatException` because you have a trailing comma and the `split()` function is going to give you an empty string at the end of your array.

Answer (score 8):

Change this

```
   System.out.println(arr);
```

to

```
   System.out.println(arr[i]);
```

before you were printing an array `arr`, not the array's elements.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're repeatedly printing the array, which will cause Java to call the array's toString() method, that will give you output like you've provided.

To fix it, try changing your loop to this:

```
for(int i = 0 ;i<str.length ; i++)
{
    arr[i]= Integer.parseInt(str[i]);
    System.out.println(arr[i]];
}
```

To give you a clearer idea what's going on, this program will do something similar:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new int[0]);
    }
}
```

It will output:

```
[I@164f1d0d
```

Answer (score 2):

By printing out the array in

```
 System.out.println(arr);
```

you effectively print out an `Object`, which happens to be the `Array` object.  That has a `toString()` method, and it tends to print out the Object's `Class` and the `hashcode()` reference.

Now, since your array is of a primitive type, it looks like this

```
[I@19821f
```

where each item means something

```
[ => "an array of"
I => "primitive integer"
@19821f => "which has a hashcode of 0x19821f"
```

Note that this is a default *convention*, meaning that while it is what you are seeing, you can't count on this reading technique with the same sense of the word guarantee.

Like many have mentioned before, you need to print out the element of the array (which won't use this pseudo-object `toString()` representation, because the element is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

remove the unnecessary sysouts to get the exact output. and in last sysout print the element not complete array.

Answer (score -2):

```
str = line.split(",");
```

If the string contains comma, then you should not use `split()`

Comment: -1: This makes no sense, and seems completely wrong. If there's a comma in the string, that's no reason not to use `split`...